# Alternate Construction heuristic and Local Search phases

Tags: optaplanner

I have a case based on MeetingScheduling example.
The results are fine.
The scheduling begin with Construction Heuristic phase.
Then there is a Local Search phase.
The CH phase reduce the hard and medium constraints penalties while the LS seems to reduce the soft constraints penalties.

I found that when I re-run the scheduling, the CH phase reduce again the hard and medium constraints penalties.
So, can we configure the solver to alternate CH et LS phases several times ?

The current solver config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solver>
  <solutionClass>org.optaplanner.examples.meetings.domain.MeetingSchedule</solutionClass>
  <entityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.meetings.domain.Meeting</entityClass>

  <scoreDirectorFactory>
    <scoreDrl>org/optaplanner/examples/meetings/solver/meetingsScoreRules.drl</scoreDrl>
  </scoreDirectorFactory>

  <termination>
    <minutesSpentLimit>20</minutesSpentLimit>
  </termination>
</solver>
```

Comment: Is there a use case of "repeated planning" (see docs, the problem changes between the 2 runs) or a use case of "reheating" (a missing feature on Late Acceptance and Simulated Annealing)? It's weird that the second CH run without problem fact changes would yield different results, unless you use nullable=true, in which case it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<solver>
  ...
  <constructionHeuristic/>
  <localSearch>
    <termination>...stepCountLimit or calculateCountLimit?...</termination>
  </localSearch>
  <constructionHeuristic/>
  <localSearch>
    <termination>...stepCountLimit or calculateCountLimit?...</termination>
  </localSearch>
  <constructionHeuristic/>
  <localSearch>
    <termination>...stepCountLimit or calculateCountLimit?...</termination>
  </localSearch>
</solver>
```

And with the programatic API you can make it dynamic to n.

That being said, this is probably the suboptimal solution. The right solution would be **reheating** (not yet supported).